# How to create tutorials/book in Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I am working on a technical tutorials website using Wordpress. I looked for ways to create tutorials i.e. Table of Contents should be in left sidebar and when user clicks on any chapter link, it should open the content in right section, but I could not any tutorials on how to do it in Wordpress. Sample tutorial the way I want to create my tutorials: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp, another example would be gitbooks.

I tried few LMS plugins but I am not planning to create complete courses and don't need additional complexity of registration, course completion etc. In plain HTML this can be done using frames but I am not sure if Wordpress has a simpler way.

I tried doing this by embedding a Nav Menu in Elementor's left layout but it doesn't looks proper and links open in new page instead of right section. In the image below, menu doesn't looks good in Astra theme and opens new page. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: I've built something similar to this... ...it's a plugin that collects posts under a custom taxonomy and then for each item in the taxonomy it creates a new "collection" of 'posts' that are categorized with that specific item.  Then using a custom template I auto generate the table of contents/navigation etc.  I can't share it because it was built for a client and it's their IP now, but if you start down the path I can help by providing advice and snippets.

Comment: You might want to look into [PressBooks](https://pressbooks.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I learned that such category of plugins in Wordpress are called "Knowledge Base"  plugins and there are several of them. In case anyone needs them going forward, there are Echo Knowledge Base,Atlas, WeDocs, BetterDocs, BasePress etc.

Comment: I built something similar to this. I used pages for chapters and child pages for sections within each chapter. The menu (table of contents) was just an itemised list of pages and subpages.